# How do i export text with formatting into an xml file, which i am exporting from powerpoint?

Tags: xml, vba, formatting, powerpoint, cdata

If there is a text like

"This is a *random* text, this should be going to xml.
This is the second ***line*** with a single sentence.

And this is the 3rd paragraph. Text is just a collection of **words**."

it should be displayed as

<[cdata[This is a < i>random< /i > text, this should be going to xml.This is the second < b >< i >line< /i >< /b > with a single sentence.< br >And this is the 3rd paragraph. Text is just a collection of < b >words< /b >."]]

and not as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each textrange has a .Runs property; .Runs tells you how many "runs" of identically formatted text there are in the range.  If all the text is formatted the same, .Runs will equal 1 and .Runs(1) returns a text range that's identical to the overall textrange.  In your example, .Runs(1) would return a range containing "This is a ", .Runs(2) would return "random" and so on.  For each run, you'd want to work out what add'l encoding to add based on .Runs(x).Font.Bold, .Italic etc.